# Java Date Validation Issue

Tags: java, validation, date

Here is the validation code for Date of format MM/dd/yyyy.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
formatter.setLenient(false);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date myDate = formatter.parse("01/02/2014888");
cal.setTime(myDate);
```

When the date string is 01/02/2014888, it passes the validation.
How can I make the validation correctly?

Comment: That is the correct and intended behavior. See the javadoc for more details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3108582/2182351 . have some cutOff year and validate

Comment: What is the best practice to validate the year?

Comment: `2014888` is a valid year, eventhough it's very far away in the future. If you want to 'validate', you need to fix a range first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Calendar` class will allow you to create dates in the future, so 2014888 is a perfectly valid year, albeit a ways off.  If you want to add additional constraints to the allowable date, you will need to check the values yourself, such as:

```
    if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) > endOfTime) {
        // do something about it
    }
```