# Date parse exception when year is not four digits

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have the following code in Java.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String expiryDateInString = "05/14/86";

final Instant expiryDate = dateFormat.parse((expiryDateInString)).toInstant();
```

I want this to cause a parse exception but i am getting a year parsed as 0086, which i believe is way in the past. How can i make the year to be a strictly 4 digit year and anything else will give an exception.

Comment: *which i believe is way in the past.* - why do you believe that?

Comment: When you are using this SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  then years in 4 digits, for 2 digits use SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

Comment: If its 2 digits or if the year is anything less than a 4 digit year. I want a parse exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [forcing 4 digits year in java's simpledateformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108561/forcing-4-digits-year-in-javas-simpledateformat)

Comment: @Adya,  op wants to prevent date with two digits year and throw expection. First understand the question and then comment.

Comment: The time when you should use `SimpleDateFormatter` is way in the past. :-) That class is now long outdated and is also notoriously troublesome. And also I don’t know of a way to persuade it to behave as you want. In any case, today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. See [AxelH’s good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50362941/5772882).

Answer (score 5):

Using `java.time` instead of the previous date API, you can use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) that will throw an exception if it is not a correct year

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu").parse(("05/14/86")
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '05/14/86' could not be parsed at index 6

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu").parse(("05/14/1986")
```

> 1986-05-14

In the opposite case, if you want to allow both 2 and 4 digit year, you can use the "optional" feature of the formatter using `[` and `]`. Providing both possible format for the year `uuuu` and `uu` in optional blocks, you will have :

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/[uuuu][uu]").parse(("05/14/86")
```

> 2086-05-14

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/[uuuu][uu]").parse(("05/14/1986")
```

> 1986-05-14